# Proceed to checkout redirecting to home page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, checkout-page

> **Error**: When i click **proceed to checkout** button from cart page then i redirect to home page.

Comment: check if you are getting something in logs.

Comment: Check your Base URL settings under:

System -> Configuration -> Web

Make sure the "Secure" URLs are correct. If you're not using SSL currently, you can either disable SSL in frontend, or set the secure base URL to the non-secure base URL.

After this, flush the Magento cache fully.  I gave this answer 24 minutes ago got 2 downvote with same time @imroz please check this if it's working then I undelete the answer somebody is hurting my reputation. Shesh also give the same link in which there is above mentioned answer

Comment: i am getting this error after my server migrate

Comment: @imroz did you checked the base url settings which I mentioned it in above comment if it's work then tell me.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Muhammad Hasham  but it not working.

Comment: ok No problem brother :)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/Checkout-wrong-redirection-Magento-1-9/m-p/8238#M1843

I hope this will help.